# Programming an NXP - LPC1313FBD48

Tags: microcontroller, usb, programmer

I was planning on flashing my mini os onto my NXP - LPC1313FBD48 ([here is a link to where I bought it](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?id=83T7141&Ntt=83T7141)) but I wasn't really sure how. So I asked but I was told that I would need a serial to usb connector. I wasn't sure if they meant something like [This](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11304) or something like [this](http://www.newark.com/microchip/ac162048/power-supply-with-rs232-cable-for/dp/04M5423). So my questions are

1. Which connector do I use and how do I pick the connector?
2. How do I use the connector with my MCU (ex. Plug one end into my usb connector and put Jumper wires onto certain ports of my MCU inorder to send the data)?

Comment: Please put the part number of the MCU in the question title and body; it's absurdly broad without that, and asking people to follow a link to a vendor catalog is impolite.  Also give the products you reference names rather than just links.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ok. I'll do that

Comment: You need to design a suitable PCB for your application, and get one made.

Comment: @LeonHeller Sorry, but I don't really understand your comment

Comment: The choice of USB serial converter would depend on the surrounding circuitry on the board rather than on the bare MCU.  If the board has RS232 level shifters, you'll want a consumer-type converter with it's own RS232 level shifters and typically a DE-9 connector.  If the board doesn't have level shifters, it will probably want a logic level cable with a rectangular header or breakout to loose wires, however there's still the question of which precise logic voltage is needed. As a **guess** probably the 3.3v, as most MCU's still have 3.3v UART pins, but high performance chips may need lower.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you have a bare LPC1313 chip (presumably on a PCB that exposes the pins) and want to program it. If you have a complete board it will likely contain an RS232 interface, in which case your first link points to a suitable usb-rs232-serial converter.

You will need an usb-to-3v3-ttl-serial converter. Your first link is an usb-to-rs232-serial converter, you would need to add an rs232-to-3v3-ttl conversion, which can be done (for instace) with a few transistors. Your second link is a power cable, which is not relevant at all.

If you don't object to pressing a few buttons when downloading (to get the chip into bootload mode) you should check one of the various usb-to-ttl-serial converters, for instance one of [these](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) by FTDICHIP.

When you want hands-off loading of your application you need a converter that provides the RTS and DTR signals. I sell a [small board](http://www.voti.nl/docs/DB100.pdf) that does just this, you could clone the design but it note that it contains an SMD chip.

An alternative could be to switch to an LPC1343, that chip adds an USB bootloader: just connect it to your PC, it will appear as a mass storage device. Copy the executable to it, disconnect, and you can start your applications. This sounds great, but in practice it is more tedious than serial bootloading.

Comment: Sorry but I am unclear on a few things in your answer: 1. it seems as though your solution is for writing applications to the MCU. I want to edit the bootloader so it can load a custom built OS. 2. I am still unsure on which part I need to use

Comment: You can't change the onboard bootloader, it is in ROM. You asked about "flashing my mini os onto my NXP - LPC1313FBD48" - no mentioning of chaning your bootloader! As to what part you need: what you you have, a bare chip? some PCB?

Comment: Oh ok. Can I edit the bootloader so that it can load my C code?

Comment: And I have a bare chip, on a PCB that exposes the wires

Comment: Using a suitable PC applicartion (lpc21isp, Flash Magic) an a serial connection you can load the .hex file generated from your C code onto the chip. You need an USB-to-serial converter, my choice would be an FT232 chip.

Comment: I've already written out an operating system in c and assembly which compiles to elf files and a binary file. How can I have the MCU load that when it powers up?

Comment: You download it to the flash of the chip, using one of the PC programs I mentioned.

Comment: **1.** Just to be clear, you are saying that I need to flash the _binary_ file to my MCU. **2.** If 1 is corect, is there a video tutorial or some kind of step-by-step that I could read to make sure that I do not mess it up? **3.** (this relates to the original question) You are saying that I need a Usb to RS232serial connector which I would connect to an rs232 to 3v3-ttl converter (which can be done with transistors) which I would connect to my MCU in order to flash the files onto the MCU? **4.** When I flash the chip is the code on it being overwritten?

Comment: 1. lpc21isp accepts either the .bin or the .hex file. 2. Not that I know. 3. that is one option, ft232 is another. 4. Yes

Comment: **1.** Is the lpc21isp this MCU or another one? **2.** would [this converter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8580) and [this](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=34M8872) work? **3.** Would I still use flashmagic to write the .bin file to the MCU? **4.** How will the bootloader know to load the .bin file? Will I need to write something to tell it to do that? **5.** Sorry for so many questions (i'm kind of new to this) What is the lifetime of the MCU?

Comment: 1,3,4: You use either lpc21isp or FlashMagic *on your PC* to download the file of your choice. 2: Your 'this' is useable, but it lacks a DTR output.

Comment: Sorry but what is DTR Output and how will that affect me?

Comment: DTR is an output from the converter to the LPC chip, and is commonly used to reset the LPC chip. RTS is then used to force the chip into bootmode. Both can be done manually (with a switch, jumper, etc) but doing it automatically is much much easier.

Comment: Ok. Are there any applications similar to Flash magic on the mac or linux?

Comment: Yes: lpc21isp, which is my favorite anyway.

Comment: Alright I will use that. Also, I have an LED and a vibrating motor that I want to come on for 7 seconds when the MCU is activated. Can I  put the LED and the Vibrating motor on any IO port and then call the ports in C (in the binary file)?

Comment: In addition, how would I use [This converter](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=34M8872) to program the MCU? Would I connect it to certain ports? If so which ones?

Comment: about the connections required for ISP: read the chapter on ISP in the manual/datasheet. About the LED and Motors: that's a totally different question, open a new question when you want to ask about writing a program. But then you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: Do you know if the converter will also work with the LPC1788FBD144?

Comment: Check the datasheet for that chip, and check whether lcp21isp supports it.

Comment: Ok. I will check the datasheet.

Comment: How can I use [this](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=34M8872) converter if the end that I use to connect to the MCU is just ports? Wouldn't I want a wire end like [this](http://www.newark.com/ftdi/ttl-232r-3v3-we/cable-ttl-to-usb-serial-converter/dp/33R1442?in_merch=true&MER=ACC_N_L5_SemiconductorsToolsAndAccessories_None)?

Comment: Check 'pin header connector' or 'pin strip connector'.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for having me look that up! It makes sense to me now. I was also wondering Which ports on the MCU I would use for programming. I cant find it on the data sheet.

Comment: All the info is in the datasheet and/or family reference manual. The UART0 pins are used for the communication. Additionally, you need the reset pin and the bootload select pin.